# How to show determinate progress bar with progress 0 to 100 when making rest api call in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: progress-bar, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to find a way to show the progress bar in my blazor webassembly web app which needs to show progress from 0 to 100 as the API is call is happening and completed.
I have seen couple of examples but it include external await Task.Delay(100) number.
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: You might consider adding more detail of how you would measure progress in the first place.

Comment: @MisterMagoo , Actually this is the doubt i also have because when i see the google search page load or any page load then i see the progress bar on top which goes from 0 to 100 showing progress, i am also reading that showing a indeterminate progress bar should be useful when we cant predict the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

So, there was a solution where we can add a listener to api and then it will send a callback to calling system during processing the request.i couldn't figure out how to do it in blazor webassembly.
So I just added the animation of progress bar going from 0 to 100 .the progress start with some predefined value and it ends once the await call is completed.
So to the user it looks like that progress bar started when request is sent and then it completes when request is fullfiled by api.
Hope this little hack will be helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).